# Need help in reading field value having comma using xml and xslt code

Tags: xml, xslt

Need help in reading field value having comma using xml and xslt code.
With the below code the output gets distorted.

So, the issue is there are multiple data each data(Employee data's) is linked with different address one of the example is shown below

here is the field data that i am trying to read
Field data - Sixth Floor, 99 Gresham Street

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl=http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
  xmlns:cs="urn:cs">
  <xsl:variable name="VAR_DELIMITER" select="','" />
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="cs">
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
  </msxsl:script>
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record[position()=1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="$VAR_DELIMITER"/>
      <xsl:text>AddressLine2</xsl:text>     
      <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record">
               <xsl:value-of select="D_Address2"/>
               <xsl:value-of select="$VAR_DELIMITER"/>  
               <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ExportDocumentTest>
               <definitions>
                  <Table Name="Header" Enabled="Y">
                    <Columns>
                        <Column Name="H_Address2" Value="AddressLine 2" Source="Text" ReportColumn="1" Enabled="Y"/>
                  </Columns>
                  </Table>  
                  <Columns>
                        <Column Name="D_Address2" DataType="string" Source="Text" Value="emp_address1"/>
                  </Columns>                       
    </definitions>
</ExportDocumentTest>
```

OUT PUT I am looking out is complete address with comma in csv file with header as Address2 and next row under this header 'Sixth Floor, 99 Gresham Street'

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example, including sample input AND the desired output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have removed the extra lines of code where i am setting the out format and extra lines of comments plus also included the desired output

Comment: The text 'Sixth Floor, 99 Gresham Street' does NOT appear in your sample input. Your stylesheet expects a root element called `Export`, containing `Record` elements, but your sample data has a root element called `ExportDocumentText` which contains a `definitions` element. Please take a little more time to fix your question.